# How to pull content of an e-mail page/template into a MailMessage Body in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-email, mailmessage

I have an e-mail template which is just a plain, static HTML page.

I need to get that page into the Body of a `MailMessage`.

Normally what I would do is just create a `StringBuilder` and append the lines over and over.  But it's kind of a long page, and I don't want to go through replacing the quotes with single quotes etc..

So is there a way to just pull in the contents of an html page into a string?  Such as:

```
emailMessage.IsBodyHtml     = true;
emailMessage.Subject        = "Test Subject";
emailMessage.Body           = GetContentsFrom("emailtemplate.html");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Quotes? 
what's wrong with File.ReadAllText("emailtemplate.html")?

Comment: What I meant by quotes was, manually doing sb.append() over and over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you replace GetContentsFrom with [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this routine would do the trick:

```
private static string GetTemplate(string templateFullPath)
{
    string template;

    if (!File.Exists(templateFullPath))
        throw new ArgumentException("Template file does not exist: " + templateFullPath);

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(templateFullPath))
    {
        template = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
    }

    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the page being hosted somewhere?  You could do this:

private string HtmlPageInToString()

{

```
WebRequest myRequest;
myRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"http://yoururlhere/");

myRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

Stream ReceiveStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);

return readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

}